# dojoquery with closest method not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I am trying to use the closest method in dojo to find out the first parent of a element which I want to show/hide based on value selected in one of filtering select. It working fine in firefox browser but in IE it says Object doesn't support Closest. Any help here is really appreciated. Given below is sample of html and js code.

HTML

```
<div class="pvrProperty pvrLayoutItem pvrPropertyRequired" id="pvr_widget_Property_3" widgetId="pvr_widget_Property_3">
<label class="pvrPropertyLabel" id="pvr_widget_Property_3_label" for="pvr_widget_editors_FilteringSelectEditor_0" data-dojo-attach-point="_labelNode">Product Type</label>
<div class="pvrPropertyEditor" data-dojo-attach-point="_editorNode">
<div class="dijitReset dijitInline idxComposite idxFilteringSelectWrap dijitValidationTextBox idxFilteringSelectWrapRequired dijitValidationTextBoxRequired dijitRequired idxFilteringSelectWrapIncomplete dijitValidationTextBoxIncomplete dijitIncomplete idxFilteringSelectWrapIncompleteRequired dijitValidationTextBoxIncompleteRequired dijitIncompleteRequired pvrEditor pvrFilteringSelectEditor" id="widget_pvr_widget_editors_FilteringSelectEditor_0" widgetId="pvr_widget_editors_FilteringSelectEditor_0">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="pvrProperty pvrLayoutItem pvrPropertyRequired" id="pvr_widget_Property_4" widgetId="pvr_widget_Property_4">
<label class="pvrPropertyLabel" id="pvr_widget_Property_4_label" for="pvr_widget_editors_FilteringSelectEditor_1" data-dojo-attach-point="_labelNode">Document Type</label>
<div class="pvrPropertyEditor" data-dojo-attach-point="_editorNode">
<div class="dijitReset dijitInline idxComposite idxFilteringSelectWrap dijitValidationTextBox idxFilteringSelectWrapRequired dijitValidationTextBoxRequired dijitRequired idxFilteringSelectWrapIncomplete dijitValidationTextBoxIncomplete dijitIncomplete idxFilteringSelectWrapIncompleteRequired dijitValidationTextBoxIncompleteRequired dijitIncompleteRequired pvrEditor pvrFilteringSelectEditor" id="widget_pvr_widget_editors_FilteringSelectEditor_1" widgetId="pvr_widget_editors_FilteringSelectEditor_1">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="pvrProperty pvrLayoutItem pvrPropertyRequired" id="pvr_widget_Property_5" widgetId="pvr_widget_Property_5">
<label class="pvrPropertyLabel" id="pvr_widget_Property_5_label" data-dojo-attach-point="_labelNode">Document Type Others</label>
<div class="pvrPropertyEditor" data-dojo-attach-point="_editorNode">
<input type="textbox"></input>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
query(".pvrPropertyLabel").forEach(function(node){
        var labelName=node.innerHTML;
        if(labelName=="Document Type"){
            alert("lableName"+labelName);
            filtertingSelectId=domAttr.get(node,"for");
            var temp=dijit.byId(filtertingSelectId).get('value');
            alert("value of filtering select is:"+temp);
        }
        else if(labelName=="Document Type Others"){
            alert("lableName"+labelName);
            //alert("query(labelNodes[i])"+query(labelNodes[i]));
            alert("equality test"+node===query(node));
            var parentNode=query(node).closest(".pvrProperty");/*node.closest(".pvrProperty") works fine here but not query(node)*/
            var spanNode=query(node).closest(".pvrPropertyLabelWrapper");
            domStyle.set(spanNode,{"width":"175px"});
            var propEditnode=dijit.byId(filtertingSelectId);
            alert("parentNode:"+parentNode);
            alert("parentNode id"+domAttr.get(parentNode,"id"));
            //var dropdownId=domAttr.get(labelNodes[i],"for");
            if(propEditnode.get('value')=="Other"){
                alert("other");
                domClass.remove(parentNode,"pvrLayoutItemHidden");
                domClass.remove(parentNode,"pvrPropertyHidden");
                domClass.add(parentNode,"pvrLayoutItem");
            }else{
                alert("not other");
                domClass.add(parentNode,"pvrLayoutItemHidden");
                domClass.add(parentNode,"pvrPropertyHidden");
                domClass.remove(parentNode,"pvrLayoutItem");
            }
        }
    });
```

Even I tried equality test to check if both nodes are same or not but they are not.If I do simple node.closest('') in above code works fine in firefox but when i use query(node).closest('') does not work in firefox also. Not sure what I am missing here. Any help is really appreciated.Thanks

Comment: which version of IE ?

Comment: I am using IE 11.0 version

Comment: had to add polyfill for closest method for IE to support it. That made it work for IE as well but I would like to know if that is correct approach or not.

Comment: did you use (require) the `dojo/NodeList-traverse` package with `dojo/query` ?

Comment: Yup I did use it as closest function is defined in that only.

Comment: Would you please self-answer your question with best solution you have found, just to help out future readers? Thanx.

Comment: Answered Andy But still I am not how effective it is but it solved my problem.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use polyfill for IE browser to support closest method.Below code solved the issue for me. Hope this helps someone facing similar issue.

```
        if (window.Element && !Element.prototype.closest) {
              Element.prototype.closest = 
              function(s) {
                  var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
                      i,
                      el = this;
                  do {
                      i = matches.length;
                      while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== el) {};
                  } while ((i < 0) && (el = el.parentElement)); 
                  return el;
              };
            }
        query(".pvrPropertyLabel").forEach(function(node){
            var labelName=node.innerHTML;
            if(labelName=="Document Type"){
                //alert("lableName"+labelName);
                filtertingSelectId=domAttr.get(node,"for");
                var temp=dijit.byId(filtertingSelectId).get('value');
                //alert("value of filtering select is:"+temp);
            }
            else if(labelName=="Document Type Others"){
                //alert("lableName"+labelName);
                //alert("query(labelNodes[i])"+query(labelNodes[i]));
                var lableId=domAttr.get(node,"id");
                //alert("labelId:"+lableId);
                var parentNode=node.closest(".pvrProperty");
                var spanNode=node.closest(".pvrPropertyLabelWrapper");
                domStyle.set(spanNode,{"width":"175px"});
                var propEditnode=dijit.byId(filtertingSelectId);
                //alert("parentNode:"+parentNode);
                //var dropdownId=domAttr.get(labelNodes[i],"for");
                if(propEditnode.get('value')=="Other"){
                    domClass.remove(parentNode,"pvrLayoutItemHidden");
                    domClass.remove(parentNode,"pvrPropertyHidden");
                    domClass.add(parentNode,"pvrLayoutItem");
                }else{
                    domClass.add(parentNode,"pvrLayoutItemHidden");
                    domClass.add(parentNode,"pvrPropertyHidden");
                    domClass.remove(parentNode,"pvrLayoutItem");
                }
            }
        });
```